# How do I convert Android Studio Project to Maven project?

Tags: android, maven

What is the way to export Android studio project to maven?  I know Studio/Gradle is more advanced build environment, but this is something I must do to fit it in with other existing projects. Should I import the Studio project into eclipse? What are the steps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*AFAIK : Till now there is no built in tool in eclipse to convert android studio project in eclipse environment but you can do it manually if needed.*

Here are few simple steps to do it manually without less chances of errors and fixing.

> Create New Eclipse Project with same package name
>
> Add Library/Reference projects
>
> Copy->Paste whole "res" folder as per eclipse project structure
>
> Copy->Paste Java src packages for classes as per eclipse project
>   structure
>
> Copy Stuff's from Manifest.xml file
>
> Setup build.xml configuration as needed anywhere in project like
>   versions..

This steps works for me..

Let's discuss for any-other workaround if anyone has..